# VSTO - How To Make IDE Show R1C1 Reference Style? And Import cond. formatting?

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-formula

Does anyone know how to use R1C1 reference style, inside the IDE for a VSTO Excel Workbook project? I cannot find it in google or in the solution, and the ribbon button thing is not available in the IDE spreadsheet.

Also - side question - anyone know why when I imported an excel file, none of the lookups or conditional formatting or named ranged imported? Anyone know how to get this to work or do I have to manually create each one? That's a huge pain, because there's literally 50+ drop downs (list validaters)/ cond. formatting / named ranged....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office Ribbon "Orb" is missing, you're right.

The way to change to R1C1 is quite simple. Close out of Visual Studio and edit the spreadsheet directly in Excel. You obviously then have the orb so can get to the options. Once saved and close you can then go back into Visual Studio.

Easy.

Sorry I can't help you with your side question. I'm not sure what you mean when you say you imported the Excel file.

Comment: Thanks! Although too late now, good to now for the future =). BTW, what I meant by 'import', was when I first created my VSTO Excel Workbook solution, it allowed me to start a blank workbook or import an existing one. I needed to import an existing one which had 7 tabs, with many formulas in it. None of the formulas imported, and neither did the pivot table - which took a very long, tedius time to manually re-create... Would great to know how to keep the formulas during this import for future reference. Thanks again